# Make a feature to mark your own question as solved by yourself already without any answer's help!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, answers, unanswered-questions

This option is way better than just setting a question as solved through checking an answer that might or might not be correct leading to a bias. And since there are many cases already that some people may solve it themselves without any answers help, this would be a neat thing to implement.

Comment: Why don't you write your own answer then, and help out others with the same problem.

Comment: because a button is more convenient rather than just typing a fully fledged answer also it would persuade more people to do so!

Comment: The purpose of the button is to help any new people seeing the post to not try to answer it since their work would be futile anyways if the question is solved. But I get your point also. Maybe make an option to post my own answer after clicking the button?

Comment: If you don't need the help anymore, and got no answer yet, simply delete. It's clicking one single button.

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron but why prevent other people from having a go at the question?

Comment: @ShifatBinRahman what for? Without having answer it is 100% useless.

Comment: `The purpose of the button is to help any new people seeing the post to not try to answer it since their work would be futile anyways` How is seeing a post that has been "solved" but contains no explanation,  helpful to anyone who needs to find a solution?  The author would be bombarded with comments asking what the solution was, and if the author replied it was "futile" because??? watch the downvotes start pouring in. I'm also guessing the question would be closed with just three flags raised by three disgruntled users.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: Wait, re-reading this again: do you expect that the site is a helpdesk? That you post a question here *for the purpose of somebody answering it for you*? That is the only context where a signal "I don't need an answer any more" would be needed. But also ***NOT THE PURPOSE OF THE STACK EXCHANGE SITES***. If you post a question that should be in order to provide value to future visitors. You're posting it so, *they* can solve *their* problem when it happens to be the same as yours. That is the reason of SE. Not for other users to help *you*.

Comment: This proposal goes against the very foundation of Stack Exchange communities

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This won't work. If you don't want to write an answer yourself after solving your question, you're probably better off just deleting your question than marking it 'solved' without providing *others* with an answer. Your question and its potential answers aren't just here for you, they're also here for all the other people that encounter the same problem.

The idea of the Stack Exchange network is to build a library of questions *and* answers, as described on the [tour page](https://stackexchange.com/tour). The answers are important: People will come here because they have the same question as you, and they are looking for an answer too. Just presenting them with 'this question is solved' but without any actual answer is just the opposite of the goal of sites on Stack Exchange, and it will frustrate those who come looking for answers.

Comment: I see I did not thought about that but what if deleting the question is also counter-intuitive as in no other people could possibly answer to that question? Wont those who do come looking for the answer be frustrated as well if they couldnt find the question itself?

Comment: @ShifatBinRahman No, because if you can't find a question about the problem you're trying to solve yet, you can ask your own. If there already is a question, any new questions are likely to be closed as [duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) and that is probably more frustrating for users than being able to ask their own question.

Comment: well thank you for clarifying that. I did not think about that before.

Comment: @ShifatBinRahman If "no other people could possibly answer ... that question", then why should the question have ever existed on SE? If you're asking a question on SE, then the question **must be** written such that *anyone* with the requisite knowledge of the subject matter can answer it. Questions should *never* require information only the OP has in order to solve them. If that's the case, then the question *needs* to be edited to include that information, or should be closed (usually as unclear/needs details or clarity) and deleted.

Answer (score 8):

If you know the answer, write it as an answer, you can even accept that answer if you want. Note that acceptance doesn't mean the answer is correct, only that it was the most helpful for the question asker. The purpose of all sites [is always](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour)

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about...

So if we just provide a button you can click without providing an answer then what value does that have to everyone except the poster of the question?

And if you don't want to answer it, why stop someone else from having a go and actually helping others?